# How can you find out your SQL connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am brand new to SQL (obviously).
I am using asp.net and an access database with some information. I am trying to make a search box so the user can easily find last names. The way I am thinking of implementing this requires me to use the SQL connection string.

How can someone find their connection string? What is should be called? Im accessing the data from gridview tool so I never had to actually type any information in to access it.

Thanks

Comment: Try find your connectionstring in web.config

Comment: You still need help with that lemme know

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use the server explorer to connect to your database.

Then right click on your database icon > select properties ... you will see the connection string copy and paste .

If you still have problem then remove the integrated security setting

**Server Explorer:**

[image]

**Properties:**

[image]

Voilà!

Comment: It gives Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\Andrew James Heid\Desktop\12\App_Data\University DB.accdb" Which is what I used at first by viewing the string when I connected. IT gives the errors of unexpected/recognized sequence and errors with the /

Comment: is it an access file you are tyring to connect to?

Comment: Yes it is an access file

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/  This site has examples of ACCESS Conn strings.